# Is there a correlation between a galaxy's rotation curve and the characteristics of its black hole?

Tags: black-holes, galaxy-rotation-curve

Do galaxies with larger mass black holes have different galaxy rotation curves than those with smaller black holes? What about other characteristics, such as whether they are spinning or dormant etc?

Comment: There definitely is a correlation between the size of the BH and the size of the rotation curves of a galaxy.  A first approximation would be, "the larger the BH, the larger the radius of the rotation curves."  This has to be modified to account for Dark Mater, Dark Energy, and the expansion   of space.  It is very likely that the correlation would not be linear.  Since the gravitational characteristics are the dominant ones, it should not matter whether the BH spins or not.